# Unable to connect different files of Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I have been trying to make a chrome extension that gives the meaning of the selected text using urban dictionary API. I have tried different approaches but unable to connect all the files for proper execution.

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Urban Dictionary",
"version": "0.1",
"description": "Dictionary based on Urban Dict.",

 "browser_action": {
   "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
"icons": {
    "16": "images/images.jpg",
    "32": "images/images.jpg",
    "48": "images/images.jpg",
    "128":"images/images.jpg"
   },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab"
  ]
 


}
```

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>meaning</title>
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>meaning</h1>
    <button id="test"></button>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <script src="getword.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "getword.js"},(results)=>{ console.log(results); } );
```

**getword.js**

```
var something;
var term = window.getSelection().toString()
fetch("https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define?term="+term, {
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "My_API_KEY",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com"
    }
})
.then(response => response.json()) 
.then(result => {
    console.log(result)
    something=result.list[0].definition
    
    }
)
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});

console.log(something)
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = something;
```

When trying to manipulate HTML using getword.js. The result comes out to be undefined.
I would be highly obliged if anyone can help me in any way to refactor this code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

In chrome extensions you always define your background scripts in `manifest file` otherwise it wont work.
like this :

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
      "back.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
```

Secondly Popup.js needs to be included in your pop.html like we normally do `<script src="popup.js"></script>`

and lastly there is another type of script that is called content script which also needs to be included in `manifest` to work at all.
like this:

```
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["jquery-3.5.0.min.js","content.js"]
    }
  ],
```

According to your need you should probably study content scripts i think.

Comment: Sorry for that I had included pop.js but just forgot to write here. The problem is i don't have any background work so no need for back.js and when defining content script the whole structure breaks

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems:

- Injected code can't make cross-origin network requests.
- getword.js's purpose is to be injected as a content script so it runs in the web page and thus shouldn't be listed in popup.html as the popup is a separate extension page in a separate window not related to the web page.

The solution is straightforward:

1. get the selected text from the web page,
2. transfer it to the popup script,
3. make the network request and show the result.

**manifest.json (MV2)** should list the API site in `permissions`:

```json
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/"
  ]
```

**popup.html:** remove `getword.js` from html and delete getword.js file.

**popup.js:**

```js
const API_HOST = 'mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com';
const API_OPTS = {
  headers: {
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'My_API_KEY',
    'x-rapidapi-host': API_HOST,
  },
};

chrome.tabs.executeScript({
  code: 'getSelection().toString()',
}, async pageData => {
  try {
    const term = pageData[0].trim();
    if (!term) throw new Error('No selection!');
    const apiUrl = `https://${API_HOST}/define?term=${encodeURIComponent(term)}`;
    const apiRes = await (await fetch(apiUrl, API_OPTS)).json();
    const def = apiRes.list[0].definition;
    document.getElementById('test').textContent = def;
  } catch (e) {
    document.getElementById('test').textContent =
      chrome.runtime.lastError ? 'Cannot access this page' : e.message;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. It really worked, all the async calls errors and DOM errors are resolved.